# How to determine if an app is using a specific sensor on Android phone?

Tags: android, android-sensors

For stats collection purposes, I want to determine if an app is using a specific sensor or not? Is there any specific API available in Android to determine this?

For example, I would like to know if a service is getting geo-location coordinates in the background and using it for something. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do the stat collection from within the same app. Android will not allow you to monitor the actions of another app (this leads to security issues).

While there is no specific Android API to monitor what the app is using, you might want to look into Google analytics which comes closest to what you are looking for. Keep in mind that this applies only from within the same app.